# Unable to include upper bound when generating random integer numbers

Tags: c#, random

I am writing a method that will generate an unsigned int between 1 and 6 (boundaries included). The current method I have is below.

```
        private static Random random = new Random();
        ...
        private static uint GetRandomChannel()
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt32(random.Next(1, 6));
        }
```

I've run this method a thousand times and I get numbers 1 through 5 but never get 6. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter to [`random.Next()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) is an *exclusive* upper bound.

> **Parameters**
>
> *minValue*: The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.
>
> *maxValue:* The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. *maxValue* must
>   be greater than or equal to *minValue*.
>
> **Return value**
>
> A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to *minValue* and less than *maxValue*; that is, the range of return values includes *minValue* but not *maxValue*. If *minValue* equals *maxValue*, *minValue* is returned.

This means that `random.Next(1, 6)` will only return values `n` in the range `1 <= n < 6`.

So for your die rolling simulation you will need to use

```
random.Next(1, 7)
```

---

**Note**: The design of this API is odd. It has special case handling for `minValue == maxValue` which seems to needlessly complicate the API. If I had designed this API I would have made both parameters be inclusive limits. This would have resulted in a pleasing symmetry and would have allowed random numbers that cover the full range of `int`.

Comment: Even more disappointingly, I've been calling random.Next(n, n+1) repeatedly and the results don't seem to be random at all!

Comment: @SeanU It's perfectly random! The only pseudo RNG that is indistinguishable from a true RNG! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

According to MSDN, the upper bound is *exclusive*, while the lower bound is *inclusive*.

[Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx)

So your code shoudl be:

```
return Convert.ToUInt32(random.Next(1, 7));
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329891%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the `random.Next` function returns a value strictly less than `MaxValue` (6 in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You can't "fix" this; it's just what [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329891%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) means to do:

> A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   MaxValue.

So if you want to generate a random integer in [a, b], you need to use `.Next(a, 1 + b)`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx), the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive.  That means that random.Next(lower, upper) will return the lower number, but it is guaranteed to never return the upper one.