# How do I generate a random uint with a maximum?

Tags: c#, random

How in C# can I generate a pseudorandom uint with some maximum? (A minimum is not needed.) There seem to be plenty of questions asking for a fully random one, but nothing with an upper limit.

Clarification: This upper limit may be greater than `int.MaxValue`, so just casting `Random.Next(int)` does not help.

Comment: [`(uint)random.Next(10000)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That returns an `int`. I need a `uint`.

Comment: You can cast an int to an uint.

Comment: Please try to do and show some research (_which_ questions did you find?) and show your code and how that doesn't work. If you can't: see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025002/unable-to-include-upper-bound-when-generating-random-integer-numbers).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Right, but that won't let me make a `uint` greater that `int.MaxValue`, defeating the point, as this is a possibility.

Comment: And what about `(uint)(random + int.MaxValue / 2)`?

Comment: @CodeCaster That's not a duplicate, I specifically need to be able to handle an upper bound greater than `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @AlphaMCubed: you haven't stated that in your question. What do you want to happen if the value is greater than `int.Maxvalue`?

Comment: You did not include that constraint in your initial question. Update your question with all relevant information.

Comment: @CodeCaster Have done so now. It seemed implicit, but I see the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply generate a number between `Int32.MinValue` and `In32.MaxValue` and shift up by half your range:

```
var random = new Random();
int number = random.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
uint uintNumber = (uint)(number + (uint)Int32.MaxValue);
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this... But wouldn't you use `random.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MinValue + maximum)`? (Considering the first int could be larger than `Int32.MaxValue / 2`, causing an overflow?

Comment: I think the math is a tad off. Thanks for accepting though.

Comment: Sure thing. Seems to be the best solution.

Comment: This seems not to work correctly. The only working solution I found was https://stackoverflow.com/a/17080161/1365061

Comment: @Alex can you explain why it seems that way?

Answer (score 3):

Idea is to generate random 4-byte array then it doesn't matter whether you convert into `Int32` or `UInt32` it's up to you:

```
var buffer = new byte[sizeof(uint)];
new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
uint result = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);

result = (result % (max - min)) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

this trick would do it

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uint MaxValue = 5555;
        uint value;
        var rnd = new Random();
        var bytes = new byte[4];

        do
        {
            rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
            value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);
        } while (value > MaxValue);

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

First, create a new object of the random class:

Random r = new Random();

Then, get your numbers out of it:

int myRandomNumber = r.Next(myMaximum + 1);

So r.Next(10) would return a number 1-9 inclusive.

Finally, cast it into uint:
myRandomUInt = (UInt)myRandomNumber;